# Question about these UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uiimage, uilabel

How can I get a UIButton like the ones at the bottom of this picutre (move and delete)? Specifically, I want an image with a text just like that.  http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_QLwms0mVa4w/SQN0MqPIpXI/AAAAAAAAAA8/lEikKn9eP_0/s1600-h/Screenshot+2008-10-25+15:31:21+-0400-1.png
Thanks.

For Jason:
The image sticks right beside the label. Is there anyway from IB I can set it to align to the left, while the label aligns to the right? Here's what it looks like right now:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is in Interface Builder, the UIButton can be set to a type of "Custom"

After you have done this, you can simply use your own image for the button and different images for each state of the button.

Although with this approach you won't be able to have additional text modified on it like the mail app has with "Delete (1)". However, if you don't need that then this solution will work for you.

Alternatively, if you just want an image stuck onto your existing button then there is an Image property in Interface Builder where you can slap on an image to your button.

If you need more functionality then you would probably have to create your own UIButton by subclassing to handle it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I used your method, but please see my original question, I have updated it with an image showing my problem with the method you described. Thanks again.

Comment: What you can do is in Interface Builder change the "Edge" insets in the properties simply choose the "Image" or "Title" in the dropdown list and modify the "Left" or "Right" insets until you are happy with how it looks.